Slim PHP: Download a file from a non-public directory
I have a Slim 4 app which has the site in a public folder. Additionally there are other directories (like app, views, etc.) including one directory called uploads where I save files submitted by the user.
We want to have a page where the file is linked. The user clicks on the file link, and this immediately downloads. The problem is the that the uploads folder is being treated as part of the public route.
In my controller I have this:
$location = __DIR__ . "/../../uploads/" . $filename;

And in my view I have:
<p><a href="{{location}}" download>{{library.uploads}}</a></p>

If the location is /home/user/public_html/project/folder1/folder2/uploads, the location is treated as sitename.com/home/user/public_html/project/folder1/folder2/uploads
How can I download the file from the uploads folder?

You are confusing file system paths like /home/user/public_html/project/folder1/folder2/uploads or C:\Windows\System32 (used to access files in your computer's disk) with URLs like https://example.com/project/folder1/folder2/uploads or https://example.com/?id=31416 (used to access network resources with an HTTP client). They are different things, just like your social security number is different from your passport number, even though both are alphanumeric strings issued by government.
Unless you plan to deploy the code in entirely different locations every time, there's no need for the URL to be dynamic:
$location = "/project/folder1/folder2/uploads/$filename";

On a side note, make sure your hosting account does not expose the entire Slim framework directory to the internet. You should have almost everything (from vendor to your PHP code) in a directory outside web server root, and only one folder (typical name is public, but it can have any name you want) with a routing script and all the assets (CSS, JavaScript, images...).
